# Trouble getting virtualenv and python to work with skypebot Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

Ubuntu 13.04

I am trying to follow these instructions here
http://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ubuntu.html#installing-sevabot

I cannot get this virtualenv to work..... ive tried a few suggestions here / irc @ #ubuntu with no luck....

http://privatepaste.com/269057399f

how do i correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some dependencies. Since you are using Ubuntu you can just install virtualenv using `apt`

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv python-pip
```

which should also install `python-setuptools`

You should now be able to run the following to setup a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv venv
```

Comment: running "sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv" yielded 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.  I then tried 
# virtualenv venv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Comment: Is the package `python-setuptools` installed?

Comment: Updated the answer. I think you also need to install `python-pip` using apt.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv python-pip
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.  What now?

Comment: If the `virtualenv` command still doesn't work I can't really help. I'd say there is something wrong with your python environment.